# Obtain access token from twitter app for oauth

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent, twitter-oauth, android-twitter

Instead of showing webview for user to enter login and password I want to make users authorize with their official twitter app (if you know, facebook api does the same - if there is installed facebook application it runs this application which returns access token).

So, maybe there are any intents for twitter application to do the same? (obtain the access token from twitter app for oauth to authorize the user in my own application)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is parsing the HTML file you receive and taking the informations that you need (oauth_verifier, authenticity_token and the text of the button where you clicked not to authorize the app). To send the user's credentials in order to authorize the app, post the credentials and the information you took from the HTML page via the `POST oauth/authorize` endpoint (undocumented on Twitter Developers). Don't hesitate to watch what the authentication with the HTML page does with tools like Firebug or Opera Dragonfly (depending on the browser you use to do this).

Comment: I didn't understand you.. what html file are you talking about? I asked about android intents to run the official twitter activity which should return authorize key via intent extra...